# Why div between tbody automatically moved out of tbody when render?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is my code :

```
<body>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <div>test</div>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

after running  the code above , it automatically changed into this:

```
<body>
    <div>test</div>
    <table>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: That's invalid HTML; the only children that a `<tbody>` can have are `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

from the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY)

```
<!ELEMENT TBODY    O O (TR)+           -- table body -->
```

Those are the only allowed tags directly inside a `TABLE` tag.

You could look also to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.1) and [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/invalid_html_ok.htm) for some insight

Answer (score 0):

Add like below.

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <div>test</div>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```